# Different Results on Full Text Search for same search on different cases on Spanish Language

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm using Full Text `CONTAINS` on SQL Server 2016 to search on a table. But if I change the case on my query I get different results. For example:

Doing this (with upper case **L**):

```
select *  FROM CONTAINSTABLE(OITM, (ItemCode),  '"L-1326*"' )
```

returns this:

- L-1326   416
- L-1326-COVER-SSS 208
- L-1326-SSS   208

---

But doing this (with lower case **'l'**)::

```
select *  FROM CONTAINSTABLE(OITM, (ItemCode),  '"l-1326*"' )
```

returns this:

- L-1326-COVER-SSS 208
- L-1326-SSS   208

---

My Full-Text Catalog is defined as follows:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG SBOWeex
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
GO
```

My FullText Index is defined like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[OITM] (
ItemCode Language 3082 
,ItemName Language 3082 
,CodeBars Language 3082
,SuppCatNum Language 3082 
) 
KEY INDEX OITM_PRIMARY
ON SBOWeex
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [OITM] SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

**Shouldn't I expect the same result on both queries?**

---

**EDIT:** I'm using Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive Collation. But my fulltext Catalog is defined with accent-sensitivity OFF. Also this appears to happen only with the combination **"L-"** and **l-** any other letter combined with "-" seems to have the same behavior in both Spanish and English parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the collation you're running. And it sounds like you're running a case sensitive collation. With Spanish, you also need to find out if you're running an accent sensitive or accent insensitive collation.

To find your database's collation, follow the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information

Then, once you know, take a look at Robert Sheldon's article [Questions About SQL Server Collations You Were Too Shy to Ask](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/questions-sql-server-collations-shy-ask/).

Comment: I'm using Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive Collation. But my fulltext Catalog is defined with accent-sensitivity OFF. So I think this shouldn't be an issue. I'll add this to the question. But thanks for the input.

Comment: Dang! Hoped that was all there was to it. Good luck, though.